# How do add leftovers from division to the last list?

Tags: bash, list, divide, bc

I'm writing a script which is designed to help me in dividing servers lists so when I'm releasing new versions of the company's products I won't have to disturb the service but only a portion of the servers, by implementing the changes on a divided list of servers each time.

The script is connecting to some internal dashboard and pulls the hostnames of the currently active servers (servers in rotation) and it's supposed to count the number of servers and based on rules which have been decided by the team, it should divide the lists to create smaller lists to work on.

So for example, if a certain data center contains 35 servers, I want the script to divide the big list to 4 not-equal lists, or if there are 10 servers I want it to divide the big list to 2 small lists.

Most of the script works already, and the only problem I have is that in some site there are 38 servers, and they apply to the rule of division by 4.

The problem is that 38 is dividable by 4 with leftovers. It seems like in the way I wrote the script the leftovers are ignored.

I'd like to add the leftovers to the last list, how can it be done?

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
site="http://10.X.X.X/dashboard/company/DCD/dcd.aspx?dcd="
tmpfile="DCD.tmp"
echo "Choose DCD:"
select DCD in 'ams2' 'ny4' 'ny4a' 'lax'  'sg' 'Quit'; do
      wget $site$DCD -O $tmpfile -nv &> /dev/null
      grep http $tmpfile | awk -F"<" '{print $7}' | awk -F/ '{print $3}' | grep -v '^$' | sort | awk -F: '{print $1}' > "$DCD"_active.list
  #   echo site: $site , DCD: $DCD
      if [[ "$DCD" = "Quit" ]]; then
      exit 0
      fi
      break
done
srvnum=$(/usr/bin/wc -l $DCD'_active.list' | awk '{print $1}')
echo "<--- List of servers: --->"
  /bin/cat "$DCD"_active.list
echo "<--- Number of active servers: $srvnum --->"
if [[ $srvnum -lt "2" ]]; then
  echo "Not enough servers"
elif [[ $srvnum -ge "10" ]] && [[ $srvnum -le "20" ]]; then
  echo "It is recommended to divide the list by 2"
  divider="2"
elif [[ $srvnum -ge "21" ]] && [[ $srvnum -le "34" ]]; then
  divider="3"
  echo "It is recommended to divide the list by 3"
elif [[ $srvnum -ge "35" ]]; then
  echo "It is recommended to divide the list by 4"
  divider="4"
fi
echo srvnum: $srvnum
echo divider: $divider
entries=$(echo $srvnum/$divider | bc)
echo "Each list will contain: $entries entries"

for i in $(seq $divider); do
    first=$(((i-1)*(srvnum/divider)+1))
    last=$((i*(srvnum/divider)))
    sed "$first,$last!d" "$DCD"_active.list | head -n$entries | tail -$entries > "$DCD"_$i.list
    done

echo "Deleting temporary files..."
rm -f "$DCD"_active.list $tmpfile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't need the `head` and `tail` int the pipeline, as the number of lines is already constrained by `sed`. Here's how you can add the reminder to the last group:

```
tail -n$(( srvnum % divider )) "$DCD"_active.list >> "$DCD"_$divider.list
```

Comment: @ItaiGanot: Sorry, I forgot to insert the filename :-)